# Converting Epoch time to date

Tags: java, android, epoch

I have some code which works out the epoch time for the first day of the current month. How would i convert this to a normal date so i can then access which day the first of the month was?

Comment: `Date` has a constructor that takes a long representing the epoch time.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this constructor being used?

Comment: `Date` is *mostly* deprecated. If possible, update to `Calendar`

Comment: try this `String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));`

Comment: it should have given me the first of march. instead it gave 28/02/44134 21:11:11

Comment: @nexus490 see this one maybe helpful [Converting Epoch time to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740972/convert-epoch-time-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

Use the SimpleDateFormat object in the Java API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Very simple and very clean.