# Git Commit Object Author and Commiter Fields

Tags: java, git, git-plumbing

I am trying to make a server using Java that runs on a Linux machine and I would like my server to support Git in a similar fashion to GitHub. I have figured out a lot of things to achieve this but there is one thing I would like to know...

Assuming I have the following Git object (with a header) deflated and stored in the file system.

```
tree d35e45b7a3ec1bfd4d91b87c16d08fc4effc6dba
parent 385f73f0f5d38c6258a7d55038c9ceb24cd63157
author ThePyroEagle <exampleEmail@example.com> 1418335844 +0000
commiter ThePyroEagle <exampleEmail@example.com> 1418335844 +0000
```

What does "1418335844 +0000" at the end mean?

I thought this might be a timestamp in milliseconds, but when I parsed it I got "17 January 1970" using the following code.

```
Date date = new Date(1418335844L);
System.out.printf("Current Time: %s\n",
        (new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy")).format(date));
```

Whatever this may be, how would I go about parsing it?

Comment: It is a timestamp, but in seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`git commit` date format](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_date_formats) states:

### Git internal format

> It is `<unix timestamp> <time zone offset>`, where:
>
> - `<unix timestamp>` is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch.
> - `<time zone offset>` is a positive or negative offset from UTC. For example CET (which is 2 hours ahead UTC) is `+0200`.

See:

- [Epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/): 1418335844 => Thu, 11 Dec 2014 22:10:44 GMT
- "[convert epoch time to date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741078/6309)"
- "[Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3371337/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. The date you got with the converter is the exact date of the commit.

Answer (score 2):

It's a timestamp in seconds: 2014-12-11T22:10:44+00:00.