# I need to understand the date format returned by cursor in android

Tags: android

What does this date means: 1427856000472?
I have got this date from cursor.getString(4).
I need the receiving date of the message, but its format is not clear to me.
Kindly help, and thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in time in milliseconds .. you need to convert them to proper time.. following thing is what i followed.. it will return date month and year 
where timestamp is equal to your time .. eg 1427856000472

```
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.text.DateFormat df= DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(mCtx);
    java.text.DateFormat df1=DateFormat.getTimeFormat(mCtx);  
    String date = (df.format(timeStamp).toString());

    String  time=df1.format(timeStamp);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
    int messageYear=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dates=cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    Locale locale=Locale.getDefault();
    String monthName=cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT , locale);

    String date =  monthName+" "+dates+"\n"+time;
```

Answer (score 1):

That time is the time elapsed since epoch(The Unix epoch is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970).

You can convert epoch time using this link:
http://www.epochconverter.com/

You can find the answer here in this post:
[convert epoch time to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740972/convert-epoch-time-to-date)

Hope this helps.